# Responsive webpage works in dev mode in Firefox, but not on my S9 Firefox

Tags: css, responsive-design

After developing a responsive webpage for practice using Pycharm and Firefox web dev tools, I uploaded it on Github. It appears to work just fine in the browser on my laptop, but when I attempt to use it on my Galaxy S9, it has the exact same font sizes as it would if I was using a laptop. It simply doesn't look like it should.

*Screenshot on laptop:*
[laptop image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmJh0.png)

*Screenshot on my phone:*
[smartphone image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjf7J.jpg)

What am I doing wrong? Here is the code if you want to [see it](https://enigma-knight.github.io/august-borne/).

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML document is missing the viewport meta tag. Try adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover" />` to the index.html file. After this has been added, the viewport in Firefox on your smartphone should conform to your mobile styles.